# When I try to run this PHP file in a browser, I get an error message

Tags: php

When I try to run this PHP file in a browser, I get the error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting :: (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)" on line 50

I also have red on lines 54 and 55 that I can't get rid of. For those two lines, the error tool tip says

> Syntax error: expected: ::,(

As far as I can see, all of my curly braces are where they need to be. I don't know what's wrong. Any ideas? Here's the code:

```
<?php

    // If a session is NOT already in progress for this
    // user, start one:
    if(!session_id()){
        session_start();
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Shopping Cart Manager</title>
        <link href="css/minismall.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php
            //Check if session cart variable exists and set shortcut:
            if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
               $cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
            }
            else { // $_SESSION['cart'] does NOT exist
               $cart = Array();
            }

            include 'catalog.php';

            // Check if ‘remove’ form field exists and set shortcut:
            if (isset($_POST['remove'])) {
                $remove = $_POST['remove'];
            }
            else { //$_POST['remove'] does NOT exist
                $remove = Array();
            }

            // Initialize $totalPrice, $prodIDStr, and session ‘numItems’
            //  variables to either 0 or empty string as appropriate:
            $totalPrice = 0;
            $prodIDStr = "";
            $_SESSION[numItems] = 0; // Did I initialize this session
                                     // variable correctly?
            //$_SESSION['numItems'] = $numItems;

            // Loop through each form field (this page is called
            // from catalog.php):

            // If a form field’s value (product quantity) is
            // a positive number (nonzero), is NOT the submit
            // button, AND the remove checkbox for removing this
            // product has NOT been checked (do these checks in one
            // condition):
            while (list($productID, $qty) = each($_POST)){
                if (($qty > 0) && (type != submit) && !isset(checkbox)){ // LINE 50

                    $cat[$productID]['qty'] += $qty; // Update the
                      // cart's element for this product with
                      // the product quantity from the form
                } //LINE 54
                Else if (($qty = 0) || isset(checkbox)){ // If the
                  // product's quantity is zero or the product's
                  // remove checkbox is checked

                    // Remove this product from the cart array:
                    //unset($_SESSION['cart'][$productID]);
                    unset($cart['productID']['qty']);
                }//END OF Else if

            }//END OF while loop

            // Connect to your database server and select your database:
            require 'dbConnect.php';

            // Loop through your cart array (foreach productID's
            // quantity in cart):
            $_SESSION['numItems'] = $cart; // Update the number of
                                           // items in your cart

            // Build a comma-delimited string in $prodIDStr containing the
            // product IDs of the products currently in our cart array:
            $prodIDStr = implode("productID, qty", $cart);

            if($_SESSION[numItems] = 0){ // If cart is empty:
                print "<h3>Your shopping cart is empty!</h3>\n";
            }
            Else { // If cart is not empty:

            // Remove trailing comma from $prodIDstr:

            // Query the database for all products in our cart
            // using the $prodIDStr ordering them
            // by category and then by productID:
            try {
                $prodIDStr = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM $cart ORDER BY $cat AND $productID");
            }
            catch (PDOException $e) {
                $error = "Error fetching product info for category $cat: " . $e->getMessage();
                include 'error.html.php';
                exit();
            }

            // Display beginning of form which calls cart_yourname.php
            // when submitted using the POST method:
        ?>

        <form action="cart_speterson86.php" method="post">

            <table>

                <tr class="header">
                    <th>Remove</th>
                    <th>Image</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Price - US$</th>
                    <th>Subtotal</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th style="background-color: #fff">&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>

                <?php
                    //
                    // Step through result set of products in this category
                    // and display each product in its own table row
                    //
                    while ($row = $itemsResult->fetch()) {

                        // Convert any special HTML characters to their HTML
                        // entities.  Example: & --> &amp;
                        //
                        // Also, strip out any HTML tags found in the data
                        $remove = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($row['loc']));
                        $imageLocation = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($row['loc']));
                        $desc = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($row['description']));
                        $price = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($row['price']));
                        $subTotal = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($row['loc']));

                        $price = "\$" . number_format($price, 2);

                        $productID = strip_tags($row['prodid']);

                        //
                        // Set $qty to contain what is in our session cart array.
                        // If your session cart array element for this product is
                        // empty, set the $qty to its default value of 0.
                        //
                        if (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$productID])) {
                            $qty = $_SESSION['cart'][$productID];
                        }
                        else {
                            $qty = 0;
                        }

                        // Build and display next product row in table
                        print <<<TABROW

                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" name="$remove[$productID]" value="1"></td>
                                <td><img src="$imageLocation" alt="groovy product $desc"></td>
                                <td class="desc">$desc</td>
                                <td class="price">$price</td>
                                <td class="price">$subTotal</td>
                                <td class="qty">
                                    <label for="quantityForProduct$productID">Qty</label>
                                    <input type="text"
                                           name="$productID"
                                           id="quantityForProduct$productID"
                                           value="$qty"
                                           size="3">
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        TABROW;

                    }  // end while another row in product result set

                ?>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" id="submitCell">
                        <input type="submit" name="addCart" value="Add Items to Cart">
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="checkOut" value="Checkout"></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="updateCart" value="Update Cart"></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </form>
    <br>

    <?php

        } // END OF Else cart is not empty

    ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: which lines are 50, 54 & 55?

Comment: Huh... I thought stackoverflow had a 'display line numbers' feature or something. Hang on a sec. I'll mark them with comments.

Answer (score 1):

You need `$` for variables and `"` for strings.

`if (($qty > 0) && (type != submit) && !isset(checkbox)){`

Probably should be:

`if (($qty > 0) && ($type != 'submit') && !isset($checkbox)){`

Same with line `55` (forgot `$`):

`Else if (($qty = 0) || isset($checkbox)){//if the product's quantity`

Comment: The second parameter on line 50: "(type != submit)" is technically a button. In the form, its name is "addCart". So you're telling me that "$addCart != submit" is the correct way to say that it hasn't been clicked yet?

Comment: To check if the user is posting use `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']==='POST')`.

Answer (score 1):

`$_SESSION[numItems] = 0;//did I initialize this session` should that have single quotes?.

Comment: PHP acts as if undefined constants were defined as a string with the name of the constant. Although it generates a notice, it works. (Not that I'd recommend relying on that.)

Comment: Notices are there for a reason.

Comment: @DaveChen: Sure, but it's obviously not the error in the question.

Comment: Ugh man, this code has many problems. OP really needs to go thru this and understand what's going on.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, something like `$id="e"; if ($id=e) echo "hi";` would work too, but it only converts text without quotes to text with quotes, not with variables.

Comment: This `$cat[$productID]['qty']+=$qty;//update the cart's element for` is causing a problem as well. Should be $ cart

Comment: I wonder if `$_POST ['submit']` `$_POST ['checkbox']` would help? Dave Chen was on to something.